# Implementing Tasks in a QGIS-Plugin to keep GUI responsive

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-plugins, gui, qthread

I am trying to implement QgsTasks into a PlugIn to keep its GUI responsive while running. I have studied the docs at https://docs.qgis.org/3.16/en/docs/pyqgis_developer_cookbook/tasks.html, which unfortunately does not cover such a case in its examples and my Python skills are obviously too low to adapt these examples to my usecase. Also I have studied similar questions like [Rewriting QgsTask abstract class?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/303723/rewriting-qgstask-abstract-class) and [How to use Threads in PyQgis, mainly to keep UI active?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/94477/how-to-use-threads-in-pyqgis-mainly-to-keep-ui-active) and [Usage of QgsTask and QgsTaskManager](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/272686/usage-of-qgstask-and-qgstaskmanager) and [How do I maintain a resposive GUI using QThread with PyQGIS](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/45514/how-do-i-maintain-a-resposive-gui-using-qthread-with-pyqgis?noredirect=1&lq=1).

However, from these docs I dont understand how to implement it properly to run a function of a PlugIn as a task with all its benefits.

Currently, I am focusing my QgsTask experiments on QgsTask.fromFunction(). I have narrowed down my code to:

```
# imports ...

MESSAGE_CATEGORY = 'My Plugin'

class MyPlugin():
    def __init__(self, iface):
        # standard content by plugin builder
        
    def add_action()#standard
        # standard content by plugin builder

    def unload(self):
        # standard content by plugin builder
        
    def do_some_work(self):        
        QgsMessageLog.logMessage("starting worker",MESSAGE_CATEGORY,Qgis.Info)
        QgsMessageLog.logMessage("before var",MESSAGE_CATEGORY,Qgis.Warning) 
        inputlayer_numberoffields = self.selectedlayer.fields().count() # Function started from class_task crashes here, can not read variable
        QgsMessageLog.logMessage("after var",MESSAGE_CATEGORY,Qgis.Warning) 
        # do heavy work

    def maplayerselection(self):
        self.selectedlayer = self.dlg.MyQgsMapLayerComboBox.currentLayer()
        
    def run(self):
        if self.first_start == True:
            self.first_start = False
            self.dlg = MyPluginDialog()
            self.maplayerselection() 
            self.dlg.StartButton.clicked.connect(self.start_work_as_task) # See below
            #self.dlg.StartButton.clicked.connect(self.do_some_work) # Everything works fine. Can be started multiple times. Gui not responsive while running
        self.dlg.MyQgsMapLayerComboBox.currentIndexChanged.connect(self.maplayerselection)
        self.dlg.show()
        result = self.dlg.exec_()
    
    #class_task = QgsTask.fromFunction('Do something', do_some_work)
    def start_work_as_task(self):
        QgsMessageLog.logMessage("start_work_as_task before starting worker",MESSAGE_CATEGORY,Qgis.Warning)
        function_task = QgsTask.fromFunction('Do something', self.do_some_work()) 
        QgsApplication.taskManager().addTask(function_task) # Starts worker function and runs correctly, but does not bring any benefits (a responsive Gui), only disadvantages like crash on second start
        #QgsApplication.taskManager().addTask(self.class_task) # Starts worker function but does not run correctly. Worker function can not read variables from other functions
        QgsMessageLog.logMessage("start_work_as_task running after starting worker",MESSAGE_CATEGORY,Qgis.Warning)
```

My "working" implementation (`function_task`) unfortunately does not bring the expected advantage of a responsive GUI. What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After a lot (and even more) of reading, trying and testing I still could not find a way to use QgsTasks in a QGIS Plugin. But with the help of mainly these two documents:

- https://realpython.com/python-pyqt-qthread/
- https://doc.qt.io/qtforpython/PySide6/QtCore/QThread.html

I was finally able to build a simple and basic **QGIS Plugin using PyQt's QThreads** and keeping the GUI active while running.

Imagine you create a QGIS Plugin called "TaskTest" using the PluginBuilder-Plugin and create a simple GUI:

[image]

The task_test.py file (explanations in the code as comments):

```py
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from qgis.PyQt.QtCore import QSettings, QTranslator, QCoreApplication, QObject, QThread, pyqtSignal
from qgis.PyQt.QtGui import QIcon
from qgis.PyQt.QtWidgets import QAction

from qgis.core import *
# Initialize Qt resources from file resources.py
from .resources import *
# Import the code for the dialog
from .task_test_dialog import TaskTestDialog
from time import sleep
from datetime import datetime
import os.path
import random

MESSAGE_CATEGORY = 'QgsTaskTestPlugin'

class Worker(QThread):
    finished = pyqtSignal() # create a pyqtSignal for when task is finished
    progress = pyqtSignal(int) # create a pyqtSignal to report the progress to progressbar
    
    def __init__(self):
        super(QThread, self).__init__()
        #print('workerinit')
        self.stopworker = False # initialize the stop variable
        
    def run(self):
        self.progress.emit(0) # reset progressbar
        self.time = 22 # just a variable to work with
        self.total = 10 # just a variable to work with
        wait_time = self.time / 100.0 # calculate the waste time
        # print('run') # debug: we just entered the run method of Worker-Class
        for i in range(self.total): # just do something
            sleep(wait_time) # just waste some time
            self.progress.emit(int((i+1)/self.total*100)) # report the current progress via pyqt signal to reportProgress method of TaskTest-Class
            if self.stopworker == True: # if cancel button has been pressed the stop method is called and stopworker set to True. If so, break the loop so the thread can be stopped
                print('break req')
                break
        self.finished.emit() # report via pyqt signal that run method of Worker-Class has been finished
        
    def stop(self):
        self.stopworker = True
        
class TaskTest:
    """QGIS Plugin Implementation."""
    
    def __init__(self, iface): # just the default generated by PluginBuilder
        # Save reference to the QGIS interface
        self.iface = iface
        # initialize plugin directory
        self.plugin_dir = os.path.dirname(__file__)
        # initialize locale
        locale = QSettings().value('locale/userLocale')[0:2]
        locale_path = os.path.join(
            self.plugin_dir,
            'i18n',
            'TaskTest_{}.qm'.format(locale))

        if os.path.exists(locale_path):
            self.translator = QTranslator()
            self.translator.load(locale_path)
            QCoreApplication.installTranslator(self.translator)

        # Declare instance attributes
        self.actions = []
        self.menu = self.tr(u'&TaskTest')

        # Check if plugin was started the first time in current QGIS session
        # Must be set in initGui() to survive plugin reloads
        self.first_start = None

    # noinspection PyMethodMayBeStatic
    
    def tr(self, message): # just the default generated by PluginBuilder
        # noinspection PyTypeChecker,PyArgumentList,PyCallByClass
        return QCoreApplication.translate('TaskTest', message)

    def add_action(
        self,
        icon_path,
        text,
        callback,
        enabled_flag=True,
        add_to_menu=True,
        add_to_toolbar=True,
        status_tip=None,
        whats_this=None,
        parent=None): # just the default generated by PluginBuilder

        icon = QIcon(icon_path)
        action = QAction(icon, text, parent)
        action.triggered.connect(callback)
        action.setEnabled(enabled_flag)

        if status_tip is not None:
            action.setStatusTip(status_tip)

        if whats_this is not None:
            action.setWhatsThis(whats_this)

        if add_to_toolbar:
            # Adds plugin icon to Plugins toolbar
            self.iface.addToolBarIcon(action)

        if add_to_menu:
            self.iface.addPluginToMenu(
                self.menu,
                action)

        self.actions.append(action)

        return action

    def initGui(self): # just the default generated by PluginBuilder
        """Create the menu entries and toolbar icons inside the QGIS GUI."""
        icon_path = ':/plugins/task_test/icon.png'
        self.add_action(
            icon_path,
            text=self.tr(u'TaskTestPlugin'),
            callback=self.run,
            parent=self.iface.mainWindow())

        # will be set False in run()
        self.first_start = True

    def unload(self): # just the default generated by PluginBuilder
        """Removes the plugin menu item and icon from QGIS GUI."""
        for action in self.actions:
            self.iface.removePluginMenu(
                self.tr(u'&TaskTest'),
                action)
            self.iface.removeToolBarIcon(action)

    def startWorker(self): # method to start the worker thread
        self.thread = QThread()
        self.worker = Worker()
        # see https://realpython.com/python-pyqt-qthread/#using-qthread-to-prevent-freezing-guis
        # and https://doc.qt.io/qtforpython/PySide6/QtCore/QThread.html
        self.worker.moveToThread(self.thread) # move Worker-Class to a thread
        # Connect signals and slots:
        self.thread.started.connect(self.worker.run)
        self.worker.finished.connect(self.thread.quit)
        self.worker.finished.connect(self.worker.deleteLater)
        self.thread.finished.connect(self.thread.deleteLater)
        self.worker.progress.connect(self.reportProgress)
        self.thread.start() # finally start the thread
        self.dlg.Test_StartTest.setEnabled(False) # disable the start-thread button while thread is running
        self.thread.finished.connect(lambda: self.dlg.Test_StartTest.setEnabled(True)) # enable the start-thread button when thread has been finished

    def killWorker(self): # method to kill/cancel the worker thread
        self.worker.stop() # call the stop method in worker class
        # print('pushed cancel') # debugging
        # see https://doc.qt.io/qtforpython/PySide6/QtCore/QThread.html
        try: # to prevent a Python error when the cancel button has been clicked but no thread is running use try/except
            if self.thread.isRunning(): # check if a thread is running
                # print('pushed cancel, thread is running, trying to cancel') # debugging
                #self.thread.requestInterruption() # not sure how to actually use it as there are no examples to find anywhere, one somehow would need to listen to isInterruptionRequested()
                self.thread.exit() # Tells the thread’s event loop to exit with a return code.
                self.thread.quit() # Tells the thread’s event loop to exit with return code 0 (success). Equivalent to calling exit (0).
                self.thread.wait() # Blocks the thread until https://doc.qt.io/qtforpython/PySide6/QtCore/QThread.html#PySide6.QtCore.PySide6.QtCore.QThread.wait
        except:
            # print('kill worker - task does no longer exist') # debugging 
            pass
       
    def reportProgress(self, n): # method to report the progress to gui
        # print(f"Long-Running Step: {n}") # debugging purposes
        self.dlg.Test_ProgressBar.setValue(n) # set the current progress in progress bar
        
    def run(self):
        # Create the dialog with elements (after translation) and keep reference
        # Only create GUI ONCE in callback, so that it will only load when the plugin is started
        if self.first_start == True:
            self.first_start = False
            self.dlg = TaskTestDialog()
            self.dlg.Test_StartTest.clicked.connect(lambda: self.startWorker()) # call the startWorker method when button has been clicked
            self.dlg.Test_Cancel.clicked.connect(lambda: self.killWorker()) # call the killWorker method when button has been clicked
            
        # show the dialog
        self.dlg.show()
        # Run the dialog event loop
        result = self.dlg.exec_()
        # See if OK was pressed
        if result:
            # Do something useful here - delete the line containing pass and
            # substitute with your code.
            pass
```

The .ui file:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ui version="4.0">
 <class>TaskTestDialogBase</class>
 <widget class="QDialog" name="TaskTestDialogBase">
  <property name="geometry">
   <rect>
    <x>0</x>
    <y>0</y>
    <width>427</width>
    <height>300</height>
   </rect>
  </property>
  <property name="windowTitle">
   <string>TaskTest</string>
  </property>
  <widget class="QDialogButtonBox" name="button_box">
   <property name="geometry">
    <rect>
     <x>30</x>
     <y>240</y>
     <width>341</width>
     <height>32</height>
    </rect>
   </property>
   <property name="orientation">
    <enum>Qt::Horizontal</enum>
   </property>
   <property name="standardButtons">
    <set>QDialogButtonBox::Cancel|QDialogButtonBox::Ok</set>
   </property>
  </widget>
  <widget class="QProgressBar" name="Test_ProgressBar">
   <property name="geometry">
    <rect>
     <x>40</x>
     <y>150</y>
     <width>161</width>
     <height>31</height>
    </rect>
   </property>
   <property name="toolTip">
    <string>&lt;html&gt;&lt;head/&gt;&lt;body&gt;&lt;p&gt;Current Progress of Task-Test&lt;/p&gt;&lt;/body&gt;&lt;/html&gt;</string>
   </property>
   <property name="locale">
    <locale language="English" country="UnitedStates"/>
   </property>
   <property name="value">
    <number>0</number>
   </property>
   <property name="textVisible">
    <bool>true</bool>
   </property>
   <property name="orientation">
    <enum>Qt::Horizontal</enum>
   </property>
   <property name="invertedAppearance">
    <bool>false</bool>
   </property>
  </widget>
  <widget class="QPushButton" name="Test_Cancel">
   <property name="geometry">
    <rect>
     <x>220</x>
     <y>150</y>
     <width>121</width>
     <height>31</height>
    </rect>
   </property>
   <property name="toolTip">
    <string>&lt;html&gt;&lt;head/&gt;&lt;body&gt;&lt;p&gt;Cancel the Task-Test&lt;/p&gt;&lt;/body&gt;&lt;/html&gt;</string>
   </property>
   <property name="text">
    <string>Cancel Test</string>
   </property>
  </widget>
  <widget class="QPushButton" name="Test_StartTest">
   <property name="geometry">
    <rect>
     <x>40</x>
     <y>100</y>
     <width>251</width>
     <height>41</height>
    </rect>
   </property>
   <property name="toolTip">
    <string>&lt;html&gt;&lt;head/&gt;&lt;body&gt;&lt;p&gt;Start the Task-Test&lt;/p&gt;&lt;/body&gt;&lt;/html&gt;</string>
   </property>
   <property name="text">
    <string>Start Test</string>
   </property>
  </widget>
 </widget>
 <resources/>
 <connections>
  <connection>
   <sender>button_box</sender>
   <signal>accepted()</signal>
   <receiver>TaskTestDialogBase</receiver>
   <slot>accept()</slot>
   <hints>
    <hint type="sourcelabel">
     <x>20</x>
     <y>20</y>
    </hint>
    <hint type="destinationlabel">
     <x>20</x>
     <y>20</y>
    </hint>
   </hints>
  </connection>
  <connection>
   <sender>button_box</sender>
   <signal>rejected()</signal>
   <receiver>TaskTestDialogBase</receiver>
   <slot>reject()</slot>
   <hints>
    <hint type="sourcelabel">
     <x>20</x>
     <y>20</y>
    </hint>
    <hint type="destinationlabel">
     <x>20</x>
     <y>20</y>
    </hint>
   </hints>
  </connection>
 </connections>
</ui>
```

Unfortunately my knowledge in this kind of stuff is still very limited, so I can not explain in detail, but as there are so few examples to find, I hope this basic example helps someone having the same questions and issues as I had/have.

Please see yourself still beeing encuraged to add your own answer so I can eventually move my accept checkmark. Or feel free to edit my answer if you can improve it.