# Running the method of QGIS plugin on a seperate thread

Tags: qgis-3, qgis-plugins, pyqgis-3

I am working on a QGIS plugin. The plugin has a main class running all the operations. I was trying to add a progress window in it. The window should load when a button is clicked running a method called "process" of same class at the back. I realized that for this I might need to use multi-threading.

Now I made changes by sending the process method to another thread. Everything works fine, except that the layer I was rendering from the the class of process method just stops working. It feels like everything has lost its connectivity. Even when I turn the layer off map canvas still keeps showing it in QGIS.

I also get this warning:

> Warning: QObject::setParent: Cannot set parent, new parent is in a different thread

Can anybody tell me what the issue could be?

Comment: You will need to add your code and some more details or your question will likely be closed. You don't say if you are using `QgsTask` or `QThread`. My guess is you are trying to load a layer from the background thread. Please see the bold warning here: https://docs.qgis.org/3.22/en/docs/pyqgis_developer_cookbook/tasks.html#introduction about unsafe thread operations from `QgsTask`. The same goes for `QThread`. If your thread class produces a layer, you can use `pyqtsignal` to emit the layer object and load it from the main thread.

Comment: You may find these recent related questions and answers useful: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/429688/setting-up-thread-with-busy-progress-indicator-or-gif-in-pyqgis, https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/430230/sharing-class-variables-across-thread-qgstasks-with-pyqgis and https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/430422/conditional-signals-in-qgstask-managing-algorithm-output

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I cannot share the code of the plugin. I am not allowed to do it. I just wanted to get an idea how this is possible theoretically.

Comment: This question/ answer here is also relevant (about QThread). It should be helpful for you: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/420003/qthread-map-not-loading-after-the-thread-is-done/420126#420126

Comment: Thanks alot for the resources.

Comment: You're welcome, the general rule is that all communication and transfer of objects between threads should be via signals. I'm sure you can find more examples if you search. Good luck.